# Unable to loop through JSON reponse in JQuery with .each method

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

I'm unable to extract object properties using the . each() method in Jquery. I'm able to view the full response with console.log (result), but I'm unable to extract from that response. I receive an undefined or [Object object] message when I attempt to use result.snippet in the .each method. When I use the .each for other json responses I'm able to extract by using data.value, but for this response it doesn't work.

```
(function getArticles(){


    var url =  "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json";
    url += '?' + $.param({
                'api-key': "",
                'q': "obama"
            });

    $.ajax({

        url: url,

        type:"GET",

        data:{


        }

       }).done(function(result) {
        console.log(result);

        $.each(result, function () {

           document.write(result.snippet); // This is not working, but works with other json responses from other API's//

        })

    });



})();
```

[image: Picture of JSON response]

Comment: Please explain how it "doesn't work", show errors, etc.

Comment: Also, what are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: Put your code in jsfiddle and explain with more details what you want.

Comment: I'm not getting an error message. I'm getting undefinedundefinedundefined on the html page. That's coming from the document.write(result.snippet); I would like to see the actual snippet. When I enter console.log(result), I see the entire response. Why can't I extract the value from that response? I can do it for all other json responses.

Comment: please include a [mcve] in the question itself, not in an image.

Comment: @Soviut https://jsfiddle.net/davidmichel212/ugdw73en/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response you're getting is an object, not an array. You can't iterate over an object. You can iterate over the keys of an object and then reference each key. In either case, you don't need jQuery to do the iteration.

```js
var response = {
  "hello": "world",
  "foo": "bar"
};

for (var key in response) {
  console.log(key, response[key]);
}
```

In your case, to get to the `snippet`:

```
response.docs[0].snippet
```

You could iterate each document:

```
response.docs.forEach(function(doc) {
    console.log(doc.snippet);
});
```

Comment: Would this be the correct way?  for ( var key in result){ console.log(key.result[snippet]);}

Comment: You should really clarify your question with what you just asked, which is "how do I get to the snippet in this response object?". I've updated the answer.

Comment: $.each(result, function () {
                console.log(result); // View entire response
                result.response.docs.forEach(function(doc) {
                    console.log(doc.news_desk);
                    console.log(doc.snippet);
                });
            })